# Rotational mechanics ( Rolling cone )

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, rotation

[image]

This is a question from Mechanics . It’s sort of similar to Irodov 1.57/1.56 question. In this question we are asked to find the angle covered .

So I first found the half angle of a cone . That’s 37degree .
But  then I was unable to write the equation for the motion of the cone .

The only equation I was able to get was V= w * r . (That’s the condition for rolling without slipping ) .

Could someone guide me in solving this problem so that I can solve this problem .

Comment: (Although after 5 months) Welcome to PSE. As a 5-months user you should know that your question is a kind of homework-and-exercises and will be closed. Also, in our questions/answers we don't post images in place of text or mathematical equations. On the other hand your question although from Mechanics is essentially on Geometry.